# SQL Server Transactional Log Full Because of a Broken Replication - Can I Shut Down the server to increase disk space?

Tags: sql-server-2008, hyper-v

I have a Dynamics NAV DB Server running SQL 2k8R2.

It was filled in this morning. This server was migrated from another Hyper-v host so e forgot about replication. Now because of this replication it filled up all the space in C.

DBCC OPENTRAN

returns

Transaction information for database 'TTT Live'.

Replicated Transaction Information:
        Oldest distributed LSN     : (56618:42207:32)
        Oldest non-distributed LSN : (56618:42727:1)
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

I took one BAK and one TRN for the same DB. But second one was not allowed since it says transactional log is full.

My question is .. CAN I SHUT DOWN THE SERVER??? Is it OK??? Since I want to EXPAND disk space for this VM on Hyper-V host 2012 R2. Since it is not ISCI I cannot do it while running.